# Objective-C issues with Location Manager

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using Location Manager. Its acting very strange. I have these UILabels in place and I am looking for away to consistently update these UILabels when the coordinates change. This is what I have in place:

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];


    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

    currentLocation = nil;

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

and then this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *) newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    /*if (currentLocation == nil)
        currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        Longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.10f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        Latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.10f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];

        LongitudeDouble = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        LatitudeDouble = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    }*/

    currentLocation = newLocation;

    Longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.10f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    Latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.10f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];

    LongitudeDouble = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    LatitudeDouble = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;

    Long.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.10f", LongitudeDouble];
    Lat.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.10f", LatitudeDouble];

}
```

My issue is when I run the app is updates the labels sometimes, but after a bit, its stops and when I close the app and reopen it the labels do not update at all.

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's only called when update to new location from old location. You can check which method first called between `viewDidAppear` and `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`

Comment: the first method called is viewDidAppear

Comment: try this method `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])`

Comment: isn't that swift? I am doing this in objective-c

Comment: It also has the method  `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` in Objective-C

Comment: I just tried it, the location does not change.

Comment: Did the `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` called?

Comment: its very inconsistent right now, its being called one and thats it, sometimes more than once.

Comment: now its being called all the time.

Comment: but my labels are not updating

Answer (score 0):

May be you should add this line `self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 0.1`

And fix your code like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 0.1
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    currentLocation = nil;  
}
```

Comment: When should I call this?

Comment: No, this did not work. My locations are not consistently updating, its almost like its being locked in and wont change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

viewDidLoad:

```
locationManager =[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] ;
locationManager.delegate=self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Info.plist:

```
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

Then

```
 -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

NSLog(@"failed to update location");
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

 CLLocation *currentLocation=[locations lastObject];

 lat=currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
 lon=currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;

 NSString *strLat=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",lat];
 NSString *strLon=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",lon];

 latitude_1=[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:strLat];
 longitude_1=[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:strLon];  
}
```